# How to express Mathieu function's first derivative in terms of Mathieu function?

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions

[Mathieu function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/28.2#vi)  $\operatorname{ce}_m(q,x)$ and $\operatorname{se}_m(q,x)$ are periodic solution of Mathieu equation, which is analogous to $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$.

However, unlike $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$, the derivative of Mathieu function $\operatorname{ce}^\prime_m(q,x)$ and $\operatorname{se}^\prime_m(q,x)$ are not equal to $-\operatorname{se}_m(q,x)$ and $\operatorname{ce}_m(q,x)$.

My question is, how to express Mathieu function's first derivative in terms of Mathieu function? **Explicitly, in the following expansion, what is the analytical expression of $A_m^k$(not in the integral form)?**
$$
\operatorname{ce}^\prime_m(q,x) = \sum_{k}a_m^n \operatorname{se}_n(q,x)
$$

If no analytical expression is available, does anyone known the existing numerical library which can generate these coefficients conveniently?

Comment: It seems like this article https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1970.pdf might contain the information you're looking for.

Comment: @ProfessorVector  you mean equation 21? it seems the one with prime is not first derivative but with argument $q'$